# Keeping first column in CSV but shifting the second column up one (JAVA)

Tags: java, csv

Say I have an already existing CSV file on my filesystem

```
0 red
1 orange
2 yellow
3 green
4 blue
```

I would like to update these results to that the first column remains, but the second column shifts up by one point like so:

```
0 orange
1 yellow
2 green
3 blue
4 (some randomly generated color)
```

Is this possible to do with Java?  I don't want to write to another file.. just update the one I am reading from.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

*Edit to show current output*

```
02         orange
03         yellow
04         green
05         blue
0 random
```

(Note: 0 and random are in the same column)

Comment: what did you try to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("csv.txt")); //or whatever the file name is
int[] numbers = new int[5];
String[] colors = new String[5];
int i = 0;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
    if (s.hasNextInt()) {
        numbers[i] = s.nextInt();
        if (s.hasNext()) colors[i] = s.next();
    }
    s.close();
    i++;
}
scan.close();

PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("csv.txt");
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    output.print(numbers[i] + " ");
    if (i + 1 < numbers.length) output.println(colors[i + 1]);
    else output.println(/* random color */);
}
output.close();
```

Comment: it should with the new code.  let me know what happens now.

Comment: it compiles now, thank you.  this is a similar issue i was having before though.  instead of keeping the first column and only updating the second, it is deleting the first row entirely.  In addition it is appending a zero before each number... After the first run, I am getting results like:

02, orange
03, yellow
04, green
05, blue
0 random color,

Comment: the random color is going into the first column in the last row.  i'm having trouble accessing specific cells rather than entire rows

Comment: I've added slightly more rigorous Scanner checking.  A few comments on your comment: (1) The file is overwritten with the new file and multiple overwrites will distort the result.  If you want to save the overwrite, you can set the PrintWriter to another file name value.  (2) Put the value of the random color between the parentheses in the last println(), where the comment about the random color is.

Comment: I edited the value String line = scanner.nextLine(); instead to scan.nextLine(); (I am guessing that was what you meant).  With the new code I am getting 0 null for the entirety of the first column.  I will try the tip you mentioned about saving the overwrite.

Comment: I suspect there is something else in the file besides the lines in question.  Variable name error fixed.  Also, make sure the input file is the original set of values.

Comment: Duh, I had the file open when I was trying to run this.. Oops!  Yeah, for clarity I have been using the original set of values each time.  Unfortunately this still removes the "1" in the first column.

Comment: what does your output look like exactly?

Comment: Edited my original post to show you code block.

Comment: It seems something is wrong with your input.  This code works on mine.  Make sure your input "csv.txt" is what you first specified.

Comment: I have it pointed to a .csv, not a .txt file -- should that matter?

Comment: also, it should't matter that I don't have headers, correct?

Comment: shouldn't matter as long as the file is written in plain text.  the file is also not SUPPOSED to have headers.